# How to import a column from SQL into Excel via BIML

Tags: sql, excel, biml

I would like to import column 'Street' (NVARCHAR(50)) from a SQL table (Practice2.dbo.Adress)  into Excel (ExcelDestination.xls).  I know how to do this in SSIS, but in BIML I can't seem to find the right code, especially to do the column mapping between source and destination.  When I try to generate the SSIS package, I get the error

> "Could not resolve reference to 'Adress' of type 'TableResource'. 'TableName="Adress"' is invalid. Provide valid scoped name."

Here is what I have done so far:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="ConnectionWithPractice2" ConnectionString="Provider='SQLNCLI11'; Data Source='DWH'; Initial Catalog='Practice2'; User Id='system'; Password='password';"></OleDbConnection>
    <ExcelConnection Name="Excel Connection Manager" ConnectionString="Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';Data Source='C:\Users\adm-jpna\Documents\ExcelDestination.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'">
    </ExcelConnection>
</Connections>
<Packages>
    <Package Name="Package1">
        <Tasks>
            <Dataflow Name="ImportIntoExcel">
                <Transformations>
                    <OleDbSource Name="OLE_DB_Source" ConnectionName="ConnectionWithPractice2">
                        <DirectInput>SELECT Street FROM Practice2.dbo.Adress</DirectInput>
                    </OleDbSource>
                    <ExcelDestination Name="Excel_Destination" ConnectionName="Excel Connection Manager">
                        <Columns>
                            <Column SourceColumn="Street"></Column>
                        </Columns>
                        <TableOutput TableName="Adress"></TableOutput>
                    </ExcelDestination>
                </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
</Packages>
```

Comment: Is your table actually `Adress` or should it be `Address`

Answer (score 1):

I made a few minor changes to your ExcelDestination

```
        <Package Name="so_45063165">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="ImportIntoExcel">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="OLE_DB_Source" ConnectionName="ConnectionWithPractice2">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT N'123 Oak' AS Street;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <ExcelDestination Name="Excel_Destination" ConnectionName="Excel Connection Manager">
                            <ExternalTableOutput Table="Sheet1$" />
                        </ExcelDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>                
        </Package>
```

TableOutput refers to the Biml collection of Tables. You're looking for `ExternalTableOutput` which instructs the engine to look to the referred object (Excel in this case) to validate that it exists. The change in tag results in the property changing from `TableName` to `Table` and then since we're referencing a worksheet and not a table, we need to specify as such with a $. `Sheet1` would be a table or named ranged while `Sheet1$` means the actual worksheet.

Since you didn't provide a column mapping between your source Street and a target column, I removed the tags.

Comment: I changed the ExcelDestination according to your answer, corrected the name of my source table, modified the ConnectionString of the Excel Connection Manager (Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES') in order to connect to an xlsx-file and now the ExcelDestination appears in the dataflow.  There is still one error though: "Error 0 : Node Excel_Destination: Could not execute Query on Connection Excel Connection Manager:
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
Could not find installable ISAM." => this error appeared prior to the change in my connection string. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your provider will need to change because JET = XLS. ACE = XLSX